# SASS/SCSS does not accept &.&

Tags: css, sass, nested

Inside my component I'd like to add a modifier, which should have a higher specification so my output should look like this:

> **Wanted output:**

```
.component {
  // ...
}

.component.component--modifier {
  // ...
}
```

> **SCSS Suggestion:**

```
.component {
  // ...
  &.&--modifier {
    // ...
  }
}
```

*But this does not work, I'm getting compile errors: Kind of "format errors" or "invalid CSS".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a mixin:

```
@mixin mod($n) {
  .#{$n} {
      color: blue;
  }
  .#{$n}.#{$n}--modifier {
       color: red;
  }
}
@include mod(component);
```

Output:

```
.component {
  color: blue;
}

.component.component--modifier {
  color: red;
}
```

But there's probably a more raisonnable approach to your real problem, like having a `modifier` class.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but shouldn't there be a native solution? Or is this really an edge case?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT Yes, this is really an edge case, you normally don't have to define dynamic classes

Answer (score 2):

You have a period next to the & (&.&). This would produce component..component--modifier, which is incorrect(two periods). What you really want is && but sass doesn't let you do this. What you want to do is escape the second & like this:

```
&#{&}--modifier
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to interpolate the second `&` by putting it into `#{&}`:

```
.component {
  // ...
  &#{&}--modifier {
    // ...
  }
}
```

*Note: The dot between the two `&` is not needed, because `&` contains it already.*

An equivalent mixin related to Densys would be:

```
@mixin modifier($modifier) {
  &#{&}--#{$modifier} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.component {
  @include modifier(breadcrumb) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** This solution doesn't work with nested modifiers.